# How can I treat double quoted data and single quoted data same in Python 2.x?

Tags: python

I have a hardcoded **metadata** file whose data is wrapped around in single quotes like 'Australia', 'USA'. This metadata is compared against **new data** which can be wrapped in either double quotes like "USA" (problem in comparing), or singles quotes (where I have no problem) . Also, I cannot compare 'USA' against "USA" .Since the new files are large ~ 700 MB , I don't want performance intensive replacement of data using replace function . How can I compare the metadata with the new data ?

Comment: so everything is either wrapped in single quotes or double quotes?

Comment: No, I am not sure of that .Files in future can have both. I am skeptical on this.

Comment: I would update the metadata files to have double quotes.  Then you can compare them directly to the new data files.

Comment: How are you comparing them? If you're loading the data into Python as strings, Python would treat both `"USA"` and `'USA'` the same (unless the quotes themselves are escaped and treated as part of the string)

Comment: Have you considered something not python for pre-processing? or is python a must? Under linux, you could try to use 'sed' or 'tr' to convert all single quote-> double quote or vice versa

Comment: I'm confused. If you cannot compare `'USA'` against `"USA"` then in what way are you trying to treat the data as "the same?" I guess the easiest way is to read the string in as the argument to `ast.literal_eval`. `ast.literal_eval(s)` is the same for `s = '"USA"'` and `s = "'USA'"`

Comment: First of all - replacement (and especially of a single character to another) - is not "performance intensive". It's less intensive than the comparison itself. Secondly - you can pre-process the old files once, to have a consistent format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use @jay's algorithm, but without imports, you may do something like:

```
def make_str(s):
    return s.strip("'").strip('"')

a = 'USA'
b = '"USA"'

c = "UN"
d = "'UN'"


if make_str(a) == make_str(b):
     print(make_str(a))

if make_str(c) == make_str(d):
     print(make_str(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
import ast
a = 'USA'
b = '"USA"'
if a == ast.literal_eval(b):
     print(a)

USA
```

Comment: For `a` this throws `ValueError: malformed string`. Besides, this is by far overkill for what I suspect to be the problem here.

Comment: Now OK. By the way, `repr(ast.literal_eval('"USA"'))` is ... `'USA'`